# In react ' const {item}= props; ' here props is an obj, then what item means? A obj of props, or a single temp obj for each obj in prop like map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import EventItem from "./event-item";

function EventList(props){
    const {items}=props;
    return(
       <ul>
           {items.map((event)=>{
               <EventItem />
           })}
       </ul>
    )
}
export default EventList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here, item is one of prop's key which pass from parent..
const {items}=props;
here with Object destructuring concept we use directly items key of props..
you can read more about below link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

This is an object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

It means that `items` will be set to the value of `props.items` (i.e. the `items` property of the passed object).

Answer (score 1):

item in this case is a property of the object.
the operation performed here is Destructuring assignment

```
object = { a: 10, b: 20 }
({ a, b } = object);
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
```